# How to apply foreach loop in angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foreach

I have a array in my controller Which has assign multiple keys with the value i need to access these values in controller so that i can save these data to database

Array is given below:-

```
 $scope.Notes['surfacedefault-1'] = { value: "xyz" };
 $scope.Notes['surfacedefault-2'] = { value: "we" };
 $scope.Notes['surfacedefault-3'] = { value: "123" };
 $scope.Notes['surfacedefault-4'] = { value: "red" };
 $scope.Notes['surfacedefault-5'] = { value: "blue" };
```

Please suggest me to access their value in controller using foreach loop

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this

```
angular.forEach($scope.Notes, function(value, key) {
  console.log(key + ': ' + value);
});
```

Also you can make use of [.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to create key value pairs in array, eg:

```
 $scope.Notes.push({'surfacedefault-1':'xyz'});
```

Answer (score 1):

use **[forEach](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach)** in angular

```
   angular.forEach($scope.Notes, function (val, key) {
        console.log(val.value)
    })
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Bala_chandran/b8xhhe7v/16/)**

Comment: Thank You It was useful for me

Comment: @AshutoshAdarsh Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

that could be a solution?

```
$scope.Notes=[
    {name:'surfacedefault-1', value: "xyz" },
    {name:'surfacedefault-2', value: "we" },
    {name:'surfacedefault-3', value:"123" },
    {name:'surfacedefault-4',value: "red" },
    {name:'surfacedefault-5',value: "blue" }];
for(var i=0;i<$scope.notes.length;i++{
    do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
var array = Object.keys($scope.Notes).map(function(key, index, array){  
   return $scope.Notes[key].value
})
```